# $A,B,C,D\in\mathbb R^2$, $A=(-1,0),D=(1,0)$, $AB, BC,CD$ has constant length, what is the locus of segment $BC$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, parametrization, locus

Denote points $A=(-1,0),D=(1,0)$, and lengths $|AB|=u$, $BC=v$, $CD=w$, where $u,v,w$ are fixed constant.

Consider $E=$ the locus of the segment $BC$, it form a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ (possibly an empty set). Can we have the explicit expression of its boundary $\partial E$?

Comment: but $BC=v$ i don't exactly un derstand what your question is

Comment: the length is fixed but points can move. @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Answer (score 0):

The locus of points $B=(x_B, y_B)$  such that have distance $u$ from $A$ is the circumference

$\mathcal{C}_A=\{(x,y) : (x-x_A)^2+(y-y_A)^2=u^2\}$

The locus of points $C=(x_C,y_C)$ such that have distance $w$ from $D$ is the circumference

$\mathcal{C}_B=\{(x,y) : (x-x_B)^2+(y-y_B)^2=w^2\}$

So your locus will be the follwing set:

$\Lambda:=\{(x,y) : \exists B\in \mathcal{C}_A , C\in \mathcal{C}_D 
and \lambda\in [0,1]  such that $

$ |BC|=v ,  (x,y)=B+\lambda (C-B)\}$

[image]

$B=(x_B, y_B)\in \mathcal{C}_A$  and $C=(x_C, y_C)\in \mathcal{C}_D$  satisfies the condition $|BC|=v$ then we have that

$(x_B-x_A)^2+(y_B-y_A)^2=u^2$

and

$(x_C-x_D)^2+(y_C-y_D)^2=w^2$

and

$(x_B-x_C)^2+(y_B-y_C)^2=v^2$

but

$(x_B-x_C)^2+(y_B-y_C)^2=(x_B-x_A)^2+$

$+(x_A-x_C)^2+2(x_B-x_A)(x_A-x_C)+$

$+(y_B-y_A)^2+(y_A-y_C)^2+2(y_B-y_A)(y_A-y_C)=$

$=u^2+ (x_A-x_C)^2+ (y_A-y_C)^2 + $

$+2(x_B-x_A)(x_A-x_C) +2(y_B-y_A)(y_A-y_C) =$

$=u^2+(x_A-x_D)^2+(x_D-x_C)^2+$

$+2(x_A-x_D)(x_D-x_C)+ (y_A-y_D)^2+$

$+(y_D-y_C)^2+2(y_A-y_D)(y_D-y_C)+$

$+ 2(x_B-x_A)(x_A-x_C) +2(y_B-y_A)(y_A-y_C) =$

$=u^2+|AD|^2+w^2+2(x_A-x_D)(x_D-x_C)+$

$+2 (y_A-y_D)(y_D-y_C)+ 2(x_B-x_A)(x_A-x_C) +$

$+2(y_B-y_A)(y_A-y_C)=4+u^2+w^2+4(x_C-1)-$

$-2(x_B+1)(x_C+1)-2y_By_C$

So you have that $B$ and $C$ must satisfies the identity

$2(x_C-x_B)-2x_Bx_C-2y_By_C=v^2-(u^2+w^2)$